# One hour offset in JSON dates

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, date

Why does this happen?

```
 new Date(2013, 5, 30).toJSON()
"2013-06-29T23:00:00.000Z"
```

It looks like one hour offset.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the local time on the machine?

Comment: It is probably the wonderful thing that is Daylight Savings Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resurrected this answer after doing investigations.

The `toJSON()` date that you see is in Z(ULU) timezone, aka UTC, whereas `Date` uses your local time zone.

The difference is easily spotted when you do this:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // should return -60 (minutes) in your case
```

Btw, daylight savings can have an effect on what you're seeing, but is not the reason why.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I was suspicius ¬¬ about that format, I hate dates :)